# Mapkit issue in finding annotation current position

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I am implementing map kit in my app and i am using this first time so please tell me how to find the current position of the annotation.?

Comment: Are you still having a problem finding the position on the annotation?  If so, please update the question with details.

Answer (score 2):

To add annotations to *MapKit* you need to implement an Annotation Delegate which implements the *MKAnnotation* protocol.  When you add the annotation to the map you create an instance of you Annotation Delegate object and then add it to the *MKMapView*.  *MKAnnotation* includes a *position* property which you can query to determine the location of the annotation:

```
@interface AnnotationDelegate : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@end
```

To add your annotation to the map:

```
AnnotationDelegate * annotationDelegate = [[[AnnotationDelegate alloc] init] autorelease];
[mapView addAnnotation:annotationDelegate];
```

Then when you get a *calloutAccessoryControlTapped* callback, you can cast the *MKAnnotationView*.annotation to your Annotation Delegate class and then query the *position* property:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    AnnotationDelegate * delegate = (AnnotationDelegate*)view.annotation;
    // do stuff with delegate.position;
}
```

Comment: @anmol-bajpai glad to hear it.

Comment: thanks this really helped me out.  i pointed to this and one other of your posts in a question of my own,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011536/iphone-mapkit-problems-viewforannotation-inconsistently-setting-pincolor